# Wrong gradient sizes in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Just noticed that gradient in Chrome is't equal. Using this css

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #00a4e4 0%, #00a4e4 50%, #369044 50%, #369044 100%);
```

In my case the left part is 657px, and the right part is 650px. This happen only in Chrome.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xML4h/3/embedded/result/)

Any fix for this?

Comment: There is something strange  going on because  elements aren't the same size due to the padding being applied  differently to each divs. See [**Revised JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/xML4h/4/embedded/result/). In any case, I'm not sure why a gradient is needed since you could just add bg color to each div.

Comment: I don't see a reason padding to cause the issue, since I'm using box-sizing: border-box and both divs are 50% width. Yes, in the example I can apply bg-color to each div, but it's more complex in the page I'm working on. Also, on the revised fiddle you posted, gradient is still messed.

Comment: Padding, when inspecting the elements does seem to cause a change in size. I agree it's odd but that's what seems to be happening.

Comment: Hmm...I just re-inspected the original and the boxes are the same size in Chrome. Could this be browser specific?

Comment: I can't duplicate either; Chromium 35 running on a KDE desktop here.